# How to use jQuery to assign value of Health Status to Hidden field?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I work on asp.net mvc I face issue i can't store value of health status on

hidden field using jQuery then pass hidden field value after get value to

Approve function when click agree button click .

on hidden field I will assign value true when checkbox Yes checked

and assign value false when check box No checked to hidden field created

then after hidden field assign value true or false .

How to get value of Hidden field true or false on approve function java script when click button agree .

```
<td style="width: 50%; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;">
             @Html.Label("HealthStatus?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
             <div class="col-md-7">
                 <input type="checkbox" id="HealthStatusTrue" name="HealthStatus" value="true" class="healthstatus-checkbox" @(Model.HealthStatus == true ? "checked" : "") />
                 Yes
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <input type="checkbox" id="HealthStatusFalse" name="HealthStatus" value="false" class="healthstatus-checkbox" @(Model.HealthStatus == false ? "checked" : "") />
                 No
             </div>
         </td>
<a id="approveControlsId" onclick="approve();" class="btn btn-primary" style="min-width: 100px;margin-top:5px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> agree </a>
```

on c# property `HealthStatus` is Boolean as below

```
public class HealthStatusData 
{ 
public bool? HealthStatus {get;set;} 
}
```

How to create hidden field then assign value of `Healthstatus` to hidden field using jQuery

```
$('.healthstatus-checkbox').on('change', function () {
   // how to assign value to hidden field 
});
```

How to pass value true or false of  hidden field to approve function java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function approve() {
// how to get hidden field Boolean value true or false here 
      }
</script>
```

**Updated Post**

answer is good but i need to replace radio button with checkbox
because i use checkbox not radio button

Answer (score 0):

I updated my answer to use a checkbox.  This is the view - I took off the question mark on the property in the model:

```
@model SO_Application.Controllers.HomeController.HealthStatusData
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index2</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
                //store value in hidden field
                if ($('#theCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#theHiddenField').val("True");
                }
                else {
                    $('#theHiddenField').val("False");
                }
            });
        });

        function approve() {
            // how to get hidden field Boolean value true or false here
            alert("The value of the hidden field is: " + $('#theHiddenField').val());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Health Status:
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HealthStatus, new { id = "theHiddenField" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.HealthStatus, new { id = "theCheckbox" })
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a id="approveControlsId" onclick="approve();" class="btn btn-primary" style="min-width: 100px;margin-top:5px;">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> agree
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for support i use checkbox can you help me replace radio by checkbox please

Comment: I updated post can you check